# How to delete a CKRecord

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

How do I delete a `CKRecord` from my database programmatically, on the client side.

```
for record in records {
    if recordNumber < 13 {
        let moodRecord:CKRecord = record as! CKRecord
        self.moodArray.append(moodRecord.objectForKey("Color") as! String)
    }
    else if recordNumber > 13 {
        // DELETE RECORD HERE
        record.delete(CKRecord)
        recordNumber--
    }
    recordNumber++
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `CKRecord`? there is no `delete` function. You should read the CloudKit user guide. It covers this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting data from cloudkit with swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681393/deleting-data-from-cloudkit-with-swift)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how you delete records in `CloudKit`. Here's how I delete records in my app:

```
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: [record.recordID])
operation.savePolicy = .AllKeys
operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { added, deleted, error in
    if error != nil {
        println(error) // print error if any
    } else {
        // no errors, all set!
    }
}
CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(operation)
```

Comment: Thank you allot! Is there a way to delete the earliest record in the database?

Comment: Each record keeps meta information including its creation time. If you want delete the earliest, query or fetch all the records, sort them by creation time and then delete the earliest one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> delete(withRecordID:completionHandler:)

[apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/1449122-delete)

objc version:

```
[aDatabase deleteRecordWithID:rec.recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecordID * _Nullable recordID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    ;
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase // or privateCloudDatabase

let recordID = someRecord.recordID
    
database.delete(withRecordID: recordID) { (ckRecordID, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
            
    guard let id = ckRecordID else {
        return
    }

    print(id)
}
```